# drop down list selected field in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

****I have 2 aspx pages default1.aspx and default2.aspx. I created a drop down list in default1.aspx. I want to retrieve the selected value of drop down list and set the label value in my default2.aspx page after i click submit button in default1.aspx page***.*

Comment: i tried using namespace and adding a function to it and tried to use that function in another aspx file but it's not happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
  Session["Value"] = DropDowlList.SelecetedValue;
  Response.Redirect("default2.aspx ");
  }
```

In default2.aspx acess that Session like this.

if it is integer

```
 int value=Convert.ToInt32(Session["Value"]);
```

if it is string

```
string value=Convert.ToString(Session["Value"]);
```

Comment: what does user name mean ??

Comment: Session is like dictionary,hold key value pair values.it means the value is stored in Session with that key name.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that default2.aspx hasn't been loaded yet, you can use one of the techniques discussed here:

http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/haissam/archive/2007/11/26/ways-to-pass-data-between-webforms.aspx

Comment: I tried it.  It worked but I had to click it several times.  Since it's an aspx form, it might need a few seconds to serve the page.